# How to replace a character at a specific position in a .txt file using commands

Tags: text, terminal, text-editor

I'm looking for a fast way to replace a character at a specific position (col 8) in a .txt just with  a terminal or some text editor

Answer (score 1):

*You need a unix tool and/or unix tool suite like coreutils, sed, awk, perl, raku, or R.*

**Using Perl(5):**

```
perl -pe 's/ ^ \w{7} \K. /----/gx;'
```

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl6):**

```
perl6 -pe 's:g/ ^ \w**7 <(.)> /----/;'
```

Sample Input:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Sample Output (either code):

```
abcdefg----ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefg----ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefg----ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
abcdefg----ijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Perl intro (abridged):
https://www.perl.com/pub/2000/10/begperl1.html/
Raku intro (13 languages!):
https://raku.guide/